# how to persist an indexed value collection in JPA

Tags: jpa

I'm trying to set up a fixed number, fixed index object structure like this:

```
Product
  Product Image 1
  Product Image 2
  Product Image 3
```

I want it to be possible to have null values, so it could have image 2 but not image 1 for example.

I would prefer to use a collection because it makes for less repetition in the UI code.

The obvious candidate would be to use an array to store the images, but from what I've read it sounds difficult for JPA to persist an array.

So I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to map this requirement to JPA collection type?

I was thinking an ArrayList but when I tried it, JPA wouldn't let me persist an ArrayList (only List). So maybe a hashmap, but it seems a little off.

Can anyone recommend how to implement a data structure for the requirement?

Comment: Why would you need an ArrayList? An ArrayList is a List that happens to use an array to store its elements, but you really shouldn't care. Use a List and annotate it with OrderColumn: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html

Comment: "JPA" doesn't let or not let you persist anything, it's just an API. You have a JPA provider, that is what decides what is possible. So if you think an ArrayList can't be persisted then why not tell us the JPA provider, and the precise error message (and stack trace). I persist ArrayList with my JPA provider all of the time

Comment: @NeilStockton: What he meant was that `@ElementCollection ArrayList<String> myList;` is not possible. I know that you mean `@ElementCollection List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();` which makes much more sense as one always should declare only the interface...

Comment: It's okay I've ended up just using a @many-to-many map with an extra column for the index. The problem with list is the empty items, so if there's no image[0], image[1] should still resolve at the same index. The behaviour i want is basically the same as you get from an array.

Comment: Why should ArrayList<String> not be possible?!

Comment: At least with Hibernate, a One to Many needs to be bound to Collection, Set or List interface. I haven't tried it with primitive types as I'm dealing with a collection of persisted entities.